# How to fetch and read emails from a specific email address in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pop3

i want to know how i can fetch and read Emails in Webforms from a specific Email Address, i have searched internet and found few solutions but now appropriate what i want? i'm using OPENPOP to fetch emails. i'm sharing my code please tell me how i can do this.

Page Class:

```
public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected List<Email> Emails
    {
        get { return (List<Email>)ViewState["Emails"]; }
        set { ViewState["Emails"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.Read_Emails();
        }
    }

    private void Read_Emails()
    {
        Pop3Client pop3Client;
        if (Session["Pop3Client"] == null)
        {
            pop3Client = new Pop3Client();
            pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
            pop3Client.Authenticate("email@gmail.com", "123456", AuthenticationMethod.TryBoth);
            Session["Pop3Client"] = pop3Client;
        }
        else
        {
            pop3Client = (Pop3Client)Session["Pop3Client"];
        }
        int count = pop3Client.GetMessageCount();
        this.Emails = new List<Email>();
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Message message = pop3Client.GetMessage(i);
            Email email = new Email()
            {
                MessageNumber = i,
                Subject = message.Headers.Subject,
                DateSent = message.Headers.DateSent,
                From = string.Format("<a href = 'mailto:{1}'>{0}</a>", message.Headers.From.DisplayName, message.Headers.From.Address),
            };
            MessagePart body = message.FindFirstHtmlVersion();
            if (body != null)
            {
                email.Body = body.GetBodyAsText();
            }
            else
            {
                body = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
                if (body != null)
                {
                    email.Body = body.GetBodyAsText();
                }
            }
            List<MessagePart> attachments = message.FindAllAttachments();

            foreach (MessagePart attachment in attachments)
            {
                email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
                {
                    FileName = attachment.FileName,
                    ContentType = attachment.ContentType.MediaType,
                    Content = attachment.Body
                });
            }
            this.Emails.Add(email);
            counter++;
            if (counter > 2)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        gvEmails.DataSource = this.Emails;
        gvEmails.DataBind();
    }
    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Repeater rptAttachments = (e.Row.FindControl("rptAttachments") as Repeater);
            List<Attachment> attachments = this.Emails.Where(email => email.MessageNumber == Convert.ToInt32(gvEmails.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value)).FirstOrDefault().Attachments;
            rptAttachments.DataSource = attachments;
            rptAttachments.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkAttachment = (sender as LinkButton);
        GridViewRow row = (lnkAttachment.Parent.Parent.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
        List<Attachment> attachments = this.Emails.Where(email => email.MessageNumber == Convert.ToInt32(gvEmails.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value)).FirstOrDefault().Attachments;
        Attachment attachment = attachments.Where(a => a.FileName == lnkAttachment.Text).FirstOrDefault();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + attachment.FileName);
        Response.ContentType = attachment.ContentType;
        Response.BinaryWrite(attachment.Content);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Email ANd Attachment Class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Email
{
    public Email()
    {
        this.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    }
    public int MessageNumber { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Attachment
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

how i can fetch email from a specific sender like "abc@def.com".

Comment: @Usama, I looked at this OpenPop documentation, it doesn't seem there is a way built in to only fetch emails with a certain sender. You could fetch all of them as you are doing now then only do whatever it is you want to do to the ones with the write From address value (using an if statement).

Comment: @Savanna thanks for your comment, is there any other way of doing this? i mean fetch and read emails from specific sender?

Comment: @Usama I've used a library called ImapX to get emails from a gmail account. It has a function that allows you to search a folder based on specific criteria. That's about as much help as I can offer you for this. See here: http://imapx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Searching%20and%20downloading%20messages&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @Savanna can i also download attachment using ImapX?

Comment: Yep. Check out their documentation, it's quite good. http://imapx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20attachments&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: @Savanna i want to implement it like a conversation? is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Savanna like facebook conversation between user and friend etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51904/discussion-between-savanna-and-usama-sheikh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get messages from just a specific user directly.  But if you don't want to download everything to find out if you need anything, use GetMessageHeaders() to get the message headers and look at the .From property to see if it matches what you want... and if it does, THEN download the e-mail's contents.